# What is best practice for date data field type in GAE-GWT?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt

This question has few sub-questions!

1. What is best data type for storing date? 
   java-s Date, or just long - in miliseconds, formated String?
2. Client/Server time-zone problem

   a) How to show date on client side (correct time zone)

   b) If client inserts date, server needs to insert date in servers timezone or better fixed app timezone? (correct api?)
3. Sorting is easy with long data type, but is it working with Date?
4. Manipulating (for example select records for last 4 days, or between two dates, etc...).

Is there any good manual for this topic!

Currently, I am using long for date data type, but it somehow does't feel right (for example browsing in admin console is confusing).
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. java.util.Date is a [supported type](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/entities.html#Properties_and_Value_Types)
2. How you show this to the user is a more generic java problem. All dates are stored in UTC. I suggest you take a look at [joda-time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) for handling timezones and dates.
3. Yes, sorting of Date objects is supported in queries etc.
4. Filtering is also supported, eg, date > yesterday && date < today. Don't forget to bear in mind there are limitations when you impose filters. For example, those inequality filters can only apply to one property at a time. See [restrictions on queries](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queries.html#Restrictions_on_Queries)

Comment: Thx. I will try! If I understand, joda-time is used on client side (GWT).

Comment: The date is stored on the server in UTC, and on the client in local time. The conversion happens automatically when the date is transferred from the server to the client, and vice versa. You don't need to use joda-time.